# How to get elementRef in fromArray in angular

Tags: angular

How to access element ref from from array. Like #cTab5.
I access the #cTab5 with viewchild in ts. but don't know how to access with form array.

```
  @ViewChild("cTab5", { static: false }) cTabE5: NbTabComponent;
 this.campaignLinesAarray().at(Index).get("cTabE5");

  <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab5>                              
   </nb-tab>
```

actually i want acces reference variable with formArray. My html like below

```
 <form [formGroup]="add_iroForm">
<div
                  class="accordion-container col-sm-10 col-12"
                  formArrayName="campaign_lines_array"
                  *ngFor="
                    let item of add_iroForm.get('campaign_lines_array')
                      .controls;
                    let i = index
                  "
                >
 <nb-tabset #tabset{{i}} id="acceptable">
  <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab1>                              
   </nb-tab>
    <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab2>                              
   </nb-tab>
    <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab3>                              
   </nb-tab>
</nb-tabset>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

if you has a reference variable in a  *ngFor, you need use -in code- [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren), if you need use in .html use the variable, Angular take account of this, e.g.

```
<div #item *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3]" >
   <button (click)="click(item)">button</button>
</div>
<button (click)="showmeAll()">button</button>

@ViewChildren('item')items:QueryList<ElementRef>
click(item)
{
   console.log(item.innerHTML)
}
showmeAll()
{
  this.items.forEach(x=>{
    console.log(x.nativeElement.innerHTML)
  })
}
```

**Update** well,

First of all, we are change a bit your .HTML, see that I get out the "formArrayName" from the *ngFor and use the same "referenceVariable" "tabset", and I add the properties [tabId] to all our tabs

```
<div formArrayName="campaign_lines_array">
  <div  class="accordion-container col-sm-10 col-12"
      *ngFor="let item of add_iroForm.get('campaign_lines_array').controls;let i = index">
     <nb-tabset #tabset id="acceptable+{{i}}">
       <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab1 [tabId]="'tab0-'+i">                              
       </nb-tab>
       <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab2 [tabId]="'tab1-'+i">                              
       </nb-tab>
       <nb-tab tabTitle="Comments" #cTab3 [tabId]="'tab2-'+i">                              
       </nb-tab>
     </nb-tabset>
   </div>
</div>
```

We can use also ViewChildren to get the tabsets

```
@ViewChildren('tabset',{read:NbTabsetComponent)items:QueryList<NbTabsetComponent>
```

or, even we can use

```
@ViewChildren(NbTabsetComponent)items:QueryList<NbTabsetComponent>
```

But, if you see the [API of TabsetComponents](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/tabs/api#nbtabsetcomponent) you see that we can do a few things with the TabSets. (only ask about routerParam). But the interest is the API of NbTabComponent. So, better get all the tabs using a viewChildren

```
  @ViewChildren(NbTabComponent) tabs:QueryList<NbTabComponent>
```

So we has all the tabs in the variable **tabs**, this allow us, e.g. in a function click, make active all the "tab2", or make active the first tab of the second tabset

```
  click()
  {
    this.tabs.forEach(x=>{
      x.active=x.tabId.startsWith("tab1")
    })
  }
  click2(index)
  {
    this.tabs.filter(x=>x.tabId.endsWith("-"+index)).forEach(x=>{
      x.active=x.tabId.startsWith("tab0")
    })
  }
```

**Update2** we can has a function to active a tab of a tabset

```
   setActiveTab(indexTabSet,indexTab)
   {
        this.tabs.filter(x=>x.tabId.endsWith("-"+indexTabSet)).forEach(x=>{
          x.active=x.tabId.startsWith("tab"+indexTab+"-")
        })
   }
```

A [fool example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bk6ac3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: actually i want acces reference variable through formArray, because reference variable already inside formArray.     this.campaignLinesAarray()
        .at(empIndex)
        .get(["tabset", 0])
    );

Comment: @MayankSudden, the tabs don't know anything about your formArray. The formArray is only a formArray, has no idea about if yu are using a input, a tabSet or whatever. Reading about Nebular, I updated the answer to show how mannage the "tabs" using ViewChildren, I hope this help you

Comment: It.showing error - Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined, also want to know how to set tabset dynamically.

Comment: has you give value to [tablId] to all your "tabs"?

Comment: I got the tab individual but want to set and get tabset dynamically, because there are more than one tabset., because use for selectTab, Ex. this.tabsetl.selectTab(this.tab1); this.tabsetl.selectTab(this.tab2); this.tabset2.selectTab(this.tab1); this.tabset2.selectTab(this.tab2);

Comment: just use `@ViewChildren(NbTabsetComponent)items:QueryList<NbTabsetComponent>`. I dont' know much abour Nebula, looking the API, I don't know how you can make a selectTab(this.tab1). I can not found in the API this method in the NbTabset. This is the reason to give a [tabId] to the tabs in the way "tab##-##", so e.g. tab0-1 is the first tab of the second tabset, and tab2-0, the third tab of the first tabset (the index begin by 0)...

Comment: ... The way I find to "select" a tab is put active=false all the tabs that belong to a tabset except the tab active. For this, first I filter all the tabs to get only the tabs that belong to a concrete tabset (`x.tabId.endsWith("-"+index)`), and then put active to false if `x.tabId.startsWith('tab'+j+'-')`, I update the answer again adding a function

Comment: When i try to set dynamically tabset like in html <nb-tabset [tabId]="'tabSet-'+i"> and ts   @ViewChildren(NbTabComponent) tabs: QueryList<NbTabComponent>;
  @ViewChildren(NbTabComponent) tabSet: QueryList<NbTabComponent>;  error appearing - Can't bind to 'tabId' since it isn't a known property of 'nb-tabse, if i will get the tabSet id like tabs , then issue will resolved.

Comment: How to get TabSet Index because tabset id is hardcoded, that's why i want to set tabSet id dynamically like tabs.

Comment: why you need access to the "tabsets"?, there's **no** method selectTab. If you want to activate a tab, you can use the last function. You need two arguments, the index of the tabset, and the index of the tab in the tabset. Has you see the stackblitz?

Comment: My issue is resolved with setActiveTab.For knowledge point view, i got the individual tab id with this line var aa = this.tabs.filter(x => x.tabId.endsWith("-" + index)); , var a1 = aa[0].tabId;, output tab0_0, similarly i try to get Tabset id , bot not successful.. Can you guide, how to achieve it. And how setActiveTab catch the tabset index, Could you explain.

Comment: can you show me a link where is defined the method setActiveTab? if this method exists, you only need use `@ViewChildren(NbTabSetComponent) tabsets:QueryList<NbTabSetComponent>` and `tabsets.toArray()[2].setActiveTab(this.tab2)`

Comment: I understood, I created three tabsets, that appearing as a index in array queryList..How can access id (id="container") which placed in markup and want to access in ts. document.getelementbyid is best or any another method in angular.. Thanks a lot.....